# Tweak tools at the top of the window in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, settings, tweak

How can I tweak tools at the top of the window in Eclipse? In particular I would like to get rid from the `Eclipse User Storage` symbol in my tools.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Oxygen 4.7, Window->Perspective->Customize Perspective